# In what order is this Python list comprehension executed?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am a bit confused by this list comprehension:

```
l = [[i * j for j in range(3, 5)] for i in range(3)]
```

In what order is it executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty vanilla list comprehension of the form:

```
[expression for var in iterable]
```

In this case, `expression` just happens to be another list comprehension.  So, the inner comprehension will evaluate once for each item yielded by the outer iterable.

It might feel a little more clear if we broke the inner comprehension out into a function:

```
def inner(i):
    return [i * j for j in range(3, 5)]

l = [inner(i) for i in range(3)]
```

Now we see more clearly (hopefully anyway) that the outer comprehension causes the inner comprehension to execute once for each "`i`" in `range(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine it being executed from the outside in.

```
[X for i in range(3)]
```

In this case, the X is itself another list comprehension:

```
[i*j for j in range(3,5)]
```

within which `i` is bound to a single value.

So it expands to `[[0*3,0*4],[1*3,1*4],[2*3,2*4]]`, or `[[0,0],[3,4],[6,8]]`,

Answer (score 0):

In the following:

```
l = [[i * j for j in range(3, 5)] for i in range(3)]
```

`i` takes on the values `0`, `1`, and `2`.  For each value of `i`, the nested list comprehension is evaluated and the result saved to the top-level list:

```
[i * j for j in range(3, 5)]
```

Here, `j` takes on the values `3` and `4`.  For each value, the product of `j` with the current value of `i` is saved.

For the first value of `i`, i.e. `0`, this is `0` times the `j` values, so you get `[0, 0]`.

For the second value of `i`, i.e. `1`, this is `1` times the `j` values, so you get `[3, 4]`.

For the third value of `i`, i.e. `2`, this is `2` times the `j` values, so you get `[6, 8]`.

The final result is the list composed of these three sub-lists, so you get:

```
[[0, 0], [3, 4], [6, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [[i * j for j in range(3, 5)] for i in range(3)]
```

can be imagined as:

```
 (1) l = [[i * j for j in range(3, 5)] with i = 0] => [[0*3, 0*4]]= [[0,0]]
+(2) l = [[i * j for j in range(3, 5)] with i = 1] =>[[0,0], [3,4]]
+(3) l = [[i * j for j in range(3, 5)] with i = 2] =>[[0,0], [3,4], [6,8]]
```